# How do i add markers on google maps to users selection on map

Tags: android, android-layout, android-mapview

I am trying to add a custom marker to the users selection on a map. this it the code i have now but seem to get a error under "add" at  "mapView.getOverlays().add(mapView);"  I want the user to select various icons and place them on the map where they are.

```
import java.util.List;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;
import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;

 public class MainActivity extends MapActivity {



@Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
 mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
 List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
 Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.androidmarker);
 CustomOverlay itemizedoverlay = new CustomOverlay(drawable, this);
 GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint((int)(24.0110 * 1E6), (int)(31.4850 * 1E6));
 MapController controller = mapView.getController();
 controller.setCenter(point);
 controller.setZoom(11);
 OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point, "Hello!", "Guess where I am?")
 itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
 mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);

 }

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event, MapView mapView) {
    if (event.getAction() == 1) {
        GeoPoint p = mapView.getProjection().fromPixels((int) event.getX(),
                (int) event.getY());
        MainActivity Overlay = new MainActivity(); 
        mapView.getOverlays().add(mapView);

        mapView.invalidate();
        GeoPoint point = mapView.getProjection().fromPixels((int) event.getX(),(int) event.getY ());
        Drawable srcdrawable = getApplicationContext().getResources().getDrawable (R.drawable.icon);
        CustomOverlay srcitemizedOverlay = new CustomOverlay(srcdrawable, getApplicationContext ());
        OverlayItem srcoverlayitem = new OverlayItem(p, "Hello!", "This is your Location.");
        srcitemizedOverlay.addOverlay(srcoverlayitem);
        mapView.getOverlays().clear();
        mapView.getOverlays().add(srcitemizedOverlay);

    }
    return false;
 }


 @Override
 protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
 return false;
 }
 }
```

Am I on the write track? and is my code correct? And can someone maybe have a link to a tutorial on how to do this.

Comment: I am getting a red line under "add" at mapView.getOverlays().add(mapView);  I don't know if i did something wrong with the code or what?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add a `MapView` as an `Overlay` to your `mapView`. So, on this line `mapView.getOverlays().add(mapView);` replace the `mapView` with the `Overlay` you want to add. But you're not gonna need that, therefore, your `onTouchEvent()` should be something like this:

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event, MapView mapView) {
    if (event.getAction() == 1) {
        GeoPoint point = mapView.getProjection().fromPixels((int) event.getX(),(int) event.getY ());
        Drawable srcdrawable = getApplicationContext().getResources().getDrawable (R.drawable.icon);
        CustomOverlay srcitemizedOverlay = new CustomOverlay(srcdrawable, getApplicationContext ());
        OverlayItem srcoverlayitem = new OverlayItem(point, "Hello!", "This is your Location.");
        srcitemizedOverlay.addOverlay(srcoverlayitem);
        mapView.getOverlays().clear();
        mapView.getOverlays().add(srcitemizedOverlay);

    }
    return false;
 }
```